# large response in Laravel

Tags: php, http, laravel

I'm sending this response:

```
$item_collections = array('@type' => 'http://activitystrea.ms/2.0/Collection',
                                     'objectID' => $stream_collections->objectID,
                                     'owner' => array('globalID'=>$stream_collections->owner),
                                     'items'=>array());

foreach($stream_collections->streamitem as $Item){

    $items = array('item'=>array(
                   'objectID' =>  $Item->objectID,
                   'targetID' => $Item->targetID,
                   'owner' =>$Item->owner,
                   'author' => array($Item->author),
                   '@type' => 'Post',
                   'published' => $Item->published,
                   'actor' => array('@type'=>'Person',
                   'displayName'=>$Item->person->displayName),
                   'object' => array('@type'=>'Note',
                       'displayName'=>$Item->text)),
                   'comments'=>$Item->comment,
                   'likes'=>$Item->like,
                   'tags'=>array(),
    );

    array_push($item_collections['items'], $items);
} return response($item_collections)
```

so if the `$Item->comment` or `$Item->like` has more than 6 comments or likes the body of the response will have some extra break lines, letters and numbers.

On the client side I'm trying to get the body using:

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
```

When i print the `$body` I get the extra break lines and letters like this:

```
9201\r\n{\"@type\":\".........}\r\n0\r\n\r\n
```

I don't know where **`9201\r\n`** and **`\r\n0\r\n\r\n`** came from. If the response is not large everything will work fine! Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: How do you print the $body?

Comment: im using echo  $body ! but im sure the problem is not with the print !

Comment: And have you tried dumping "response($item_collections)" on the server side? Is it ok?

Comment: yes and the response is normal with out the extra break lines and the letters !

Comment: how are you fetching the data from the server side?

Comment: @ jedrzej.kurylo    `fwrite($fp, "\r\n"); 
            $response = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }

            //get the body
            list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);`

Comment: Did you check if you have any `echo` or `print` in your code that might be outputting that numbers (`9201` and `0`)?